# LayoutInflater inflate fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

There are hundreds of similar questions referring to problems with fragments in Android SDK. I've read them all and tried samples, but my program doesn't work.

I've created a `NavigationActivity` (`extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`) to create a `DrawerLayout`. First child is the main content (activity provides that id). Second child of the drawer should be the fragment of the navigation. Since everything is dynamic, I use many small layouts. Here is my fragment layout (navigation_activity_fragment.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        class="de.spinnerban.wildoak.view.fragments.NavigationFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my `NavigationActivity` I try to merge the views:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_activity);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mainContent = LayoutInflater
            .from(getApplicationContext()) 
            .inflate(
               getContentResId(), // concrete activity returns id of the main content (abstract method)
               drawerLayout,
               false);

    navigationFragmentContainer = LayoutInflater
            .from(getApplicationContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.navigation_activity_fragment, drawerLayout, false); // EXCEPTION line 35 (XML above)

    drawerLayout.addView(mainContent);
    drawerLayout.addView(navigationFragmentContainer);
}
```

Without fragment my program worked well. Now with fragments I got this.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.fragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.spinnerban.wildoak-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:665)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:65)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at de.spinnerban.wildoak.util.activity.NavigationActivity.onCreate(NavigationActivity.java:35)
            ...
```

Activity's `onCreate` method is invoked and then the inflater tries to find `class android.view.fragment` and of course this is wrong. Why does the inflater treat the fragment as view class?

What I've already did is:

- use `ActionBarActivity`
- use `Activity` (without support)
- use `FragmentActivity`
- use `class` attr in fragment-tag
- use `android:name` attr in fragment-tag

My gradle compiles `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0`

```
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
```

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man, I don't know why, but everything changes. I had the idea to create an activity with fragment out of the Android Studio to have a look at the code and there seem to be no `<fragment>`-tags anymore.

The solution:

1. create a container view (with id or tag!) to add the fragment
2. use the support fragment manager and start a transaction to add the fragment to the id or tag (I don't know why, but 'add to a view' doesn't work since there is no `View` param, so we have to set id or tag of the container!)

navigation_activity_fragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_container"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
>
</LinearLayout>
```

NavigationActivity.java:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(
            R.id.navigation_container,
            new NavigationFragment()
        )
        .commit();
}
```

This solution has another great advantage: we can pass parameters to the fragment via ctor.

I'd like to thank everybody here. I was very desperate.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is no class known as `android.view.fragment`. There is `android.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Looks like an import error from where I'm looking, though frankly I have no idea how you could have gotten that to even *compile* in the first place.

The error is originating from the `onCreate()` method of your `NavigationActivity`, which you haven't posted.

**EDIT:**

I'm convinced that the problem in your original code is that you are using

```
class = "de.spinnerban.wildoak.view.fragments.NavigationFragment"
```

instead of

```
android:name = "de.spinnerban.wildoak.view.fragments.NavigationFragment"
```

If it doesn't make a difference the first time, try uninstalling the APK and running the app again from the IDE. The method you have used: adding a `Fragment` to a `LinearLayout` programmatically, is also correct, but your original code should work with this small change.

Comment: I didn't import `android.view.fragment`. I thought, that the inflater builds the class from `android.view` and the tag. The fragment tag is the only lowercase tag I know (and `<include>`), so the inflater must treat them different, is that right?

Comment: post that `Activity` first

Comment: Sorry I edit my post. The onCreate you can read above is the `NavigationActivity`

Comment: Yeah sorry again, I edit my post again. It's the second inflate where the fragment's XML gets loaded

Comment: do you have any idea :( ?

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fix it, see `What I've already did is:`. I answer my question, but cannot mark it as solution till tomorrow. There are no fragment tags anymore I think.